# Serving static files in express net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: node.js, express

My folder structure is :

```
APP
 -public
   main.js
 -views
   index.html
 index.js
```

I am trying to serve the static file to express server but its not working. The code for this in my index.js file is:

```
const express = require('express'),
      app     = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
```

I have also tried using path.join syntax

In my index.html file in the views folder , I am using the src tag as 'main.js'

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

I get the error net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. 
I can also see that path src is referring to is wrong. 
It is looking for main.js file in views directory instead of looking in public directory.

I have looked at other answers. I understand the syntax theoretically but am not able to find what I am doing wrong

Please point out the issue in my code. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `app.use(express.static(__dirname+'../public'));`

Comment: just tried it.. getting the same error

Comment: Lol.. sure am sorry I thought the `index.js` file was inside another directory. I just checked docs they suggest this approach now `app.use(express.static('public'))`

Comment: no issues :)..well i tried that too , doesnt work...infact its better to use the absolute path so that the path is valid even if we access the static files from somewhere other than the project directory..I have done this many times before..dont know what seems to be the issue this time..

Comment: Can you investigate in dev tools, if the `main.js` file is being correctly imported? Like there are no other trailing slashes.

Comment: in the console the path is => APP/views/main.js . Whereas I need file to be imported from  => APP/public..If i change the src = '../public/main.js' then it works..but it doesnt automatically look inside the public folder for static files right now..there are no trailing slashes

Comment: mmh, try `<script type="text/javascript" src="/main.js"></script>`

Comment: Cause it seems it's getting the `main.js` from `views` and not the root defined by `app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));`

Comment: that is also not working :(..yes thats the issue..it's looking at the defined public path. that middleware seems to be having no effect..i am failing to understand the reason

Comment: Hi..I was able to fix this issue...I had just added the index.html in my project directory without serving the file in any of the routes..So in my routes I added the code to render my  index.html file  simply like res.sendFile('index.html)..and it worked.

Comment: Awesome! Next time try to share as much code as possible.

Comment: will do.. Thanks for all the effort!

Comment: You're welcome! ✨✨

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example:

`index.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './views/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`server is listening on port ${port}`));
```

`./public/main.js`:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  console.log('onload');
};
```

`./views/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    This is template
  </body>
</html>
```